# Cloud Formation AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup VpcId takes a string?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to write a cloud formation template which sets up a security group for a load balancer. I have the following to select a VPC for the SecurityGroup:

```
"Parameters" : {
  "VpcId" : {
    "Description" : "VPC associated with the provided subnets",
    "Type" : "List<AWS::EC2::VPC::Id>"
  },
},
```

And then to create the load balancer security group I have:

```
"LbSecurityGroup" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
  "Properties" : {
    "GroupDescription" : "Stack LBs",
    "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "VpcId" }
  }
},
```

When I launch the stack it fails with:

```
CREATE_FAILED   AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup LbSecurityGroup
Value of property VpcId must be of type String
```

First of all, why the heck isn't AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup.VpcId of type AWS::EC2::VPC::Id? And second of all, how do I massage that into a string?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The additional, more specific types (like `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup` instead of just `String`) are new, and are only used for parameters - the purpose is to validate that resources exist before trying to create the stack. See [Using the New CloudFormation Parameter Types](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx3DV2UYG9SC38G/Using-the-New-CloudFormation-Parameter-Types) for more information.

In your case I believe the problem is that type of the `VpcId` parameter is a list of `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup` values, though, and not a single `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup` value? The `VpcId` property of `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup` resources takes only single strings, not lists of strings - see [VpcId](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html#cfn-ec2-securitygroup-vpcid).

Comment: Yes, AWS::EC2::VPC::Id is a newer specific type I am trying to use for the parameter selection. VpcId parameter in AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup is of type string, but when I use the parameter via "Ref" I don't get a string instead get an error.

Comment: Because you have defined your parameter to be `List<AWS::EC2::VPC::Id>` instead of `AWS::EC2::VPC::Id`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the user to choose **one** VPC from a dropdown list, then use AWS::EC2::VPC::Id.

If you want the user to select **one or more** VPCs from a checkboxlist, then use List<AWS::EC2::VPC::Id>.

Comment: The `VpcId` property of `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup` takes only a single string, not a list of strings, so the latter is not going to work in this case.

Comment: @bsvingen Yes, he has used the wrong type in his Vpcid parameter because in this case he needs a single VPC id. I think we're saying the same thing but I'm just pointing out in the more general case when it would be appropriate to use one type over the other.